# Scanner.nextLine(); not reading first name and last name

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

So I'm trying to get the user to input their first and last name. I tried using Scanner.next(); but that only reads the first name (the first token), but I also need the Scanner to read the last name. So I did the following:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Player1 player1 = new Player1();
System.out.print("Please write your first name and last name: ");
player1.setName(sc.nextLine());
```

So here is my code. I wanted that the scanner reads the first and the last name and passes that into the method setName which saves the input into a variable located in the Player1 class.

Now when I compile and start the program it just prints out the statement "Please write your first name and last name" but after that I can't enter nothing.

```
Player1 player1 = new Player1();
Player2 player2 = new Player2();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Write your first and last name: "); 
player1.setName(sc.nextLine());
System.out.print("\nWrite your first and last name: ");
player2.setName(sc.nextLine());
```

Now this code is pretty much the same except that I wan't the second user to input their first and last name as well. Here when I compile the program I cannot enter any information after the first statement but after that I can only input the first and the last name for the second user.

What is going on here ? I would appreciate all the help !

Comment: Are you sure this is the code which generated the behavior you describe?

Comment: The code works if you ask me (depends of the body of `setName(String)` method). Probably you're pressing ENTER first when you see the message to provide first- & last name.

Comment: *Why* did you create two *(presumably identical)* player classes named `Player1` and `Player2`? Why not just two instances of a common `Player` class?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Works fine: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/v9WaiF)

Comment: You said you used `next()` but your code shows `nextLine()`. ???

Comment: You'll need describe your input to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried executing your program and it works fine.

However I feel that you are pressing Enter key after getting the below line on console for the first time

```
Write your first and last name
```

Without pressing Enter key, just type the name of the first user. Then press enter and it will ask you for second user credentials.

You can also use println and modify the message in your program as

```
        Player player1 = new Player();
        Player player2 = new Player();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write your first and last name");
        player1.setName(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Write your first and last name");
        player2.setName(sc.nextLine());
```

Comment: Hi Tom,
Both print() with "\n" and println() give the same result.
It's my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @Tom Don't know that \n may fail depending on OS. Thank you for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Do you want to continue ? y/n ?");
        String yesOrNo = sc.next();


        System.out.println("Please write your first and last name");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please write your first and last name");
        String name2 = sc.nextLine();
```

I fixed it a little bit but there was another peace of code above that. When I removed it everything started working fine. But what was wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is years old, but I just ran into the same problem and couldn't find the solution on the web. However, I tried experimenting and just added a space between scanner objects. Like so...

```
System.out.println("Please enter your full name:");
String name = scanner.next() + " " + scanner.next();
```

And it registered as a first and last name. I hope this solution works for anyone else. It at least works for inputting information into an SQL database.

Answer (score -1):

I would try assigning the result of calling sc.nextLine() to a string instead of passing it directly to a method.

String player1name = sc.nextLine();
player1.setName(player1name);

This may help you isolate your problem.

Comment: System.out.print("Write the first and the last name"); 
String name1 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nWrite the first and the last name");
String name2 = sc.nextLine();

Comment: [Why? It leads to the same behavior, only with some storage to a local variable...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042979/scanner-nextline-not-reading-first-name-and-last-name#comment75112322_44043129)